# Spring Boot Service A calls a Spring Boot B and getting 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I have a Spring Boot Service **A** calling a Spring Boot **B**. When both services are running locally, it works without problems. If I deploy the Spring Boot **B** into a container on cloud, I'm always getting 404 Not Found error.

Weird thing: if I call the same URL of Spring Boot **B** in terminal (with cURL) or in Postman it works. Just through Spring Boot Service **A** doesn't work.

I'm calling the service in the class below and during the execution the error is on webClient.post() method.

```
@Component
public class DetalleCtaContratoPorCuentaContratoFacade {

    @Value("${url.base}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Value("${uri.consultarDetalleCtaCtoPorCuentaContratoQuery}")
    private String consultarDetalleCtaCtoPorCuentaContratoQueryUri;

    public ConsultarDetalleCtaCtoResponseRoot getDetalleCtaCto(
            DetalleCtaContratoRequestParam detalleCtaContratoRequestParam, HttpHeaders headers) {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(baseUrl);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String response = webClient.post()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(consultarDetalleCtaCtoPorCuentaContratoQueryUri)
                        .build(detalleCtaContratoRequestParam.getUrl()))
                .headers(OpenAPI2SpringBoot.consumer(headers))
                .bodyValue(detalleCtaContratoRequestParam).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();

        try {
            return mapper.readValue(response, ConsultarDetalleCtaCtoResponseRoot.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new DefaultErrorException(MensajeInterrupcionUtil.getMessaje("DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE"));
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
2022-05-04 11:31:09 DEBUG o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions - [2d02d7f5] Response 404 NOT_FOUND
2022-05-04 11:31:09 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found from POST https://gateway-portalescge-uat.lfr.cloud/RESTAdapter/OFVCGE_Q/DistribucionDatosMaestros/CuentaContrato/ConsultarDetalleCtaCtoPorCuentaContratoQueryResponse_Out] with root cause
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found from POST https://gateway-portalescge-uat.lfr.cloud/RESTAdapter/OFVCGE_Q/DistribucionDatosMaestros/CuentaContrato/ConsultarDetalleCtaCtoPorCuentaContratoQueryResponse_Out
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:185) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ 404 from POST https://gateway-portalescge-uat.lfr.cloud/RESTAdapter/OFVCGE_Q/DistribucionDatosMaestros/CuentaContrato/ConsultarDetalleCtaCtoPorCuentaContratoQueryResponse_Out [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:185) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:206) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:378) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.11.RELEASE.jar:0.9.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:373) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.11.RELEASE.jar:0.9.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:429) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.11.RELEASE.jar:0.9.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:645) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.11.RELEASE.jar:0.9.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.11.RELEASE.jar:0.9.11.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1526) ~[netty-handler-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1275) ~[netty-handler-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1322) ~[netty-handler-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[netty-codec-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[netty-codec-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1680) ~[reactor-core-3.3.9.RELEASE.jar:3.3.9.RELEASE]
        at cl.cge.api.facade.DetalleCtaContratoPorCuentaContratoFacade.getDetalleCtaCto(DetalleCtaContratoPorCuentaContratoFacade.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
        at cl.cge.api.ConsultarDetalleCuentaContratoController.detalleCuentaContrato(ConsultarDetalleCuentaContratoController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at cl.cge.util.JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthorizationFilter.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

However, if I call the same URL in Postman I will get an 200 OK:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Someone in my team has figured it out that it was the CORS configuration.

In my CORS configuration I've added the option `allowedHeaders(*)`. So, in my Spring Boot Application Class I've now the bean as below:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*").allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Besides that, I've notice that in my headers the `host` parameter was always with `localhost:8080` and never with the remote URL. Removing the `host` parameter it worked perfect too.

```
    public static HttpHeaders setHost(HttpHeaders headers) {
        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.HOST);
        return headers;
    }
```

Both changes made the remote configuration works as expected.

Comment: Suggestion: It would be more useful for future visitors to this question if the answer describes the specific solution. As it stands, the current answer is more of a comment than an actual answer.

Comment: hi @andrewJames , thank you! I've added more information in my answer above to make it clear to others :)

Comment: thanks, i faced exact same problem and was able to resolve after spending 1 day of debugging and then looking into this post

Comment: I had the same issue, just removing the header Host worked for me